# Explanation sought on a job with OTE

Tags: salary

what does the following ( picked out from a job announcement) mean ?

Salary: £30,000 OTE after 1st year + Benefits (basic £21-24K + Commission)

Thank you in advance; I am curious to understand what it really means.

Comment: Since you are asking about £, is the job you are interested in located in the UK? If not, where is it located?

Comment: yes it is ibdeed.

Answer (score 5):

OTE stands for [“On Track Earnings”](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-target_earnings), meaning how much you can expect to earn including both your salary and a typical amount of commissions. This ad offers to pay you 21-24 thousand, and says you’ll likely  be making up to an additional 6 thousand a year in commissions after you’ve been at it for a year or so.

Comment: That phrase again.... "up to". The devil is in the details.

Comment: @Justin indeed. Zero is in the stated range.